# Taxonomy Parameters in WP Query to get posts from two different taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

For example I have custom post type Cars and two custom taxonomies Brand (with terms BMW, Honda, etc.) and Color (Red, Green, etc.).

Car must has Brand but may not have Color.

So it may be like: Car -> Brand : BMW -> Color : Red,

and aslo it may be like this:

Car -> Brand : BMW(without color).

I need to get Cars from 1 brand which has colors: Car -> Brand : BMW -> Colors (any color). I have tryed to create query but it does not work.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bmw'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color'
        )
    )
);
$query = get_posts( $args );
var_dump($query);
die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*terms* parameter of tax query is required. Just pass to it all the terms for taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bmw'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => get_terms('color', array('fields'=>'ids') )
        )
    )
);
```

Note this query will also returns 'cars' that have no brand attached, but have a color.

Comment: Ths for answer! But small modification - 'relation' => 'AND'

Comment: @Alexander, I've copied 'OR' from your question. Using 'AND' cars with a brand, but without a color, will not retrieved.

Comment: Yes, OR was in my code. But i am trying to get Cars from BMW brand with any color and has fail with OR(this query selects cars from different Brand, not only BMW). So with AND it gets Cars only from Brand BMW and only that which has colors. Ths again!